# How to set value of private field or property in a component depending on parameter value

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

My code:

Parent:

```
<ChildComponent UserName="@userName"/>
```

Child component:

```
<button disabled="@disableForwardToUser">OK</button>

@code {
[Parameter]
public string UserName { get; set; }

private bool disableForwardToUser = false;
}
```

Now what I would like, is to have the private filed `disableForwardToUser` set depending on the value of `UserName` when the component is loaded, something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
{
    disableForwardToUser = true;
}
```

I have tried to set it directly on the filed, and also to set in from a constructor, but got the message that I cannot set the value of a field that way from a parameter. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use any events, just a simple getter.

```cs
<button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@_disableForwardToUser">OK</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? UserName { get; set; }

    private bool _disableForwardToUser => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.UserName);
}
```

The component renders every time `UserName` changes.

Here's my test page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <ChildComponent UserName="@_userName" />
</div>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.UpdateName>Change User</button>
</div>

@code {
    private string? _userName;

    private void UpdateName()
        => _userName = _userName is null ? "Fred" : null;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! However, now the disableForwardToUser is read only, how do I give it a "setter"? I tried to do it like this, but it didnt work:

`private bool disableForwardToUser
{
    get => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.UserName);
    set;
}`

Comment: Why do you want a setter?  How will you set it?  It's conditional based on the value of `this.UserName`.

Comment: I actually don't need it in this particualr case, but I'm using the same code in another case where I also need to set the value of the filed in a function in the component. How do I combine the lambda expression on `get` with the "normal" auto setter `set;` so that the filed is not ready only?

Comment: Add another field that your process sets and then do an `AND` or an `OR` in `disableForwardToUser` to get the correct boolean answer.

Comment: Or if this doesn't work, post another Question on here with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I have created a separate question with example code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75542495/how-to-set-setter-on-property-in-combination-with-lambda-on-get

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `OnInitialize` method of child component as follows:

```
 <h3>ChildComponent</h3>
    <button disabled="@disableForwardToUser">OK</button>
    @disableForwardToUser
    
    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    
        private bool disableForwardToUser = false;
    
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
            {
                disableForwardToUser = true;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `OnParametersSet()` is better, since you'd like the parameters to actually be set first.

Comment: You're right, However, Oskar said that: `when the component is loaded`

Comment: [Polite]  Perfectly valid answer (using OnParametersSet), but you don't need to use any lifecycle methods.  The component renders every time `UserName` is updated so `disableForwardToUser `  can be a simple getter.  See my answer below.

Comment: Interesting to see it could be done this way too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also full implement getter and setter for public property and assign the private variable each time the set occurs:

```cs
    private string? username;
    [Parameter]
    public string? Username {
        get => username; set {
            username = value;
            disableForwardToUser = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Polite]  This is not a good way to do it.  You should only declare parameters with a standard `{get; set;}`.  They should never be modified, and hanging processes from them will delay the setting process.  In this case you are doing something pretty simple, but once you cross that boundary others will think it's OK to do all sorts of things.

Comment: I suppose that performance impact depends on how many times the setter is invoked vs how many times the private property will be called. 
Anyway if the Username change, the property need to be recalculated too, so I don't think that there is an ovehead, eventually you could check if the new value is equal to the old and avoid to do the calculus. In case of a Blazor component tipically the input property is set only once.
I think that auto-implemented properties (standard) are a great enhancement, but the classical implementation of getter and setter could be used without problems if needed.

Comment: I beg to politely disagree.  Let's look at your example.  You are linking the Parameter to an internal field.  Let's now say that an internal process in `OnParametersSet` sets `userName` to another value.  You now have an inconsistency between what the Renderer believes the value to be and what it actual is.  This can cause diffing issues and the UI getting out of sync with the RenderTree.

Comment: The advice I believe comes from the Blazor team, though I can't find the relevant reference at the moment.  You can do what you like, and if you know what your doing get away with it.  Many on here who read answers don't have that level of knowledge, and believing it's Ok to add stuff to the getters and setters of Parameters, will quicky get into trouble.

Comment: In my code the [Parameter] is related to the public `Username` property and not to the `username` private backing field. So in theory noone could access the backing field from external code (except if Reflection is used). Anyway I understand your comments and concerns. Since I didn't find source code to see how the `ParameterAttribute`works under the hook, I agree that it's better to avoid my solution. I will further investigate, did you have some documentation? Thanks