# How to set "setter" on property in combination with lambda on get

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using a lambda expression to set the value on my `claimed` field. This apparently causes the field to be read only, according to the error message in this screenshot:

[image]

How do I set the auto setter on the filed? I have tried to do it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
private bool claimed
{
    get => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
    set;
}
```

Code from screenshot:

```
<input @bind="name" />

<button @onclick="HideClaimedBy">Hide Claimed By</button>

@if (claimed)
{
    <p>Claimed by: @name</p>
}

@code {
    private string? name;

    private bool claimed => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);

    private void HideClaimedBy()
    {
        claimed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the value wouldn't do anything, since the property getter is reading `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)` as its value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372457/lambda-for-getter-and-setter-of-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a manual override of your `claimed`?

Maybe something llike that?

```
    private bool? _claimedOverride;
    private string name;
    private bool claimed
    {
        get => _claimedOverride ?? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
        set => _claimedOverride = value;
    }
```